# How to I call a list or generator within a String formatter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Wish to pad numbers from 1 - 99 like so:

001 002 ... 099

- I can print the list

```
x = [x + 1 for x in range(99)]
print(x)
```

- or make a generator object

```
def gen99():
    gen = 10
    end = 99
    while gen < end:
        for x in range (end):
            yield gen
            gen += 1

#f = gen99()
#next(f)
```

- I can pad a single number

```
Padded = "{:0=3}"
print(Padded.format(1))
```

- I cannot combine these things

Comment: `[f"{n:03}" for n in range(1,99)]`

Comment: `[f"{n:03}" for n in f]`

Comment: ' '.join([f'{k:03d}' for k in range(1, 99)])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you need to call the generator properly:

```
def gen(start, end):
    for x in range(start, end):
        yield x

Padded = "{:0=3}"
for x in gen(10, 100):
    print(Padded.format(x))
```

But you can use a generator comprehension as well:

```
generator = (f"{x:0=3}" for x in range(10, 100))
for el in generator:
    print(el)
```

**Edit:**
If you want to use `next` syntax:

```
generator = gen(10, 100)
element = next(generator)
print(Padded.format(element))
```

Comment: Damn, you folks are clever! tyty

Answer (score 0):

Unless I don't understand the question then surely it's as simple as:

```
print(' '.join(f'{n:03}' for n in range(1, 100)))
```

**Output:**

001 002 002 ... 099

**Note:**

Not a list comprehension but a generator. Range is 1->99 inclusive